# How to create pdf package using PdfBox?

Tags: itext, pdfbox

I was migrating some code (originally using iText) to use PdfBox for PDF merging. All went fine except creating PDF packages or portfolios. I have to admit I was not aware that this existed until now.

this is a snippet of my code (using iText):

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, out);
stamper.makePackage(PdfName.T);
stamper.close();
```

I need this but with PdfBox.

I'm looking into API and docs for both and I can not find a solution atm. Any help would be great.

PS. Sorry if I made impression that I need solution in iText, I need it in PdfBox because migration is going from iText to PdfBox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know PDFBox does not contain a *single, dedicated* method for that task. On the other hand it is fairly easy to use existing *generic* PDFBox methods to implement it.

First of all, the task is effectively defined to do the equivalent to

```
stamper.makePackage(PdfName.T);
```

using PDFBox. That method in iText is documented as:

```
/**
 * This is the most simple way to change a PDF into a
 * portable collection. Choose one of the following names:
 * <ul>
 * <li>PdfName.D (detailed view)
 * <li>PdfName.T (tiled view)
 * <li>PdfName.H (hidden)
 * </ul>
 * Pass this name as a parameter and your PDF will be
 * a portable collection with all the embedded and
 * attached files as entries.
 * @param initialView can be PdfName.D, PdfName.T or PdfName.H
 */
public void makePackage( final PdfName initialView )
```

Thus, we need to change a PDF (fairly minimally) to make it a portable collection with a tiled view.

According to section 12.3.5 "Collections" of ISO 32000-1 (I don't have part two yet) this means we have to add a **Collection** dictionary to the PDF catalog with a **View** entry with value **T**. Thus:

```
PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(...);

COSDictionary collectionDictionary = new COSDictionary();
collectionDictionary.setName(COSName.TYPE, "Collection");
collectionDictionary.setName("View", "T");
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = pdDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
catalog.getCOSObject().setItem("Collection", collectionDictionary);

pdDocument.save(...);
```

Comment: to elaborate, PDF Portfolios, it seems, is a way to make a user-friendly depiction of the attached documents. So essentially, creating a Portfolio is a two-step process - first create a document with attachments, then add the above code suggested by mkl to create a user-friendly tiled "view" of these attachments. both PDFBox Cookbook and examples show how to do the first step: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/workingwithattachments.html